# AspectJ Weaver setter pattern issue

Tags: java, aspectj, setter

I have a "working" AspectJ Weaver pattern for matching all the setters inside a certain type (Item):

```
public pointcut setter(Item item) :
    target(item)
    && execution(void Item+.set*(*));
```

It works just swell for all the potential setters, but it also matches methods with names like "setup" that takes one argument.

So my solution right now is to check in the method that intercepts all setters if the 4th character is lowercase or not (based on thisJoinPoint.getSignature().getName()), and based on that not continue with the code.

But is there a better way to exclude all methods that have a lowercase character after "set"? As far as I know regular expressions are not part of AspectJ patterns, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is less ugly, but you could introduce an annotation @NoSetter and use this in another `pointcut noSetter`to *exclude* the methods like `setup(...)` where you do not want the aspect applied:

```
public pointcut noSetter(Item item) :
target(item)
&& execution(void @NoSetter Item+.*(..));
```

Modify the pointcut `setter` as follows:

```
public pointcut setter(Item item) :
target(item)
&& execution(void Item+.set*(*))
&& !noSetter();
```

I've used this approach in a situation where setter methods needed to fire a certain event. We could not generate the code and doing this by hand was too tedious and error-prone. Also, on some setters the event was to be explicitly not fired at all.

[The above syntax is untested, don't have an IDE right now to verify this]

Comment: Thanks. I guess this is the closest I can get to a clean solution. Not really the best, since this is a very large enterprise project that is taken over late in the development process. But it works nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but there are other ways around that problem.
If you're just trying to avoid the setup method, you could add && !execution(void Item+.setup(*))

You could also use the ugly solution of adding && !execution(void Item+.seta*(*)) && !execution(void Item+.setb*(*)) && !execution(void Item+.setc*(*)) and so on ...

Or if you know something else about the methods you want to avoid you could a combination of adding this() or cflow() pointcuts.